# What can android listen for while asleep?

Tags: android, bluetooth, nfc, android-powermanager

I can't find a list of events that can be listened for while a device is sleeping.

For example, it is possible to use **[LocationListener while asleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030460/android-locationlistener-leave-on-while-phone-asleep).**

> My goal is to detect when a user is in his car by at least one of the
>   following methods, which will then wake the phone:
>
> - NFC tag on car dock
> - Bluetooth-enabled car radio in range

But failing those, I'm open to ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create a brodcast receiver and register specific actions.

An example to detect a boot: [Android -Starting Service at Boot Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562734/android-starting-service-at-boot-time).

Comment: Thanks - I already use a broadcast receiver for NFC tags and Bluetooth devices, they work while the device is awake but not while asleep.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea so far is to wake the phone periodically as per this link:

[Android - periodically wake up from standby mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579027/android-periodically-wake-up-from-standby-mode)

As per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html), I could wake the phone up and just use the CPU, while keeping the screen off.

But there might be disadvantages, perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: *argh* Please avoid this if possible. It's what causes the battery to drain rapidly if not used responsibly by the apps (- which often think they're so important that I really want them to run every few seconds or so :-E).

Comment: I agree.. it's a pretty nasty way of doing it